# Personalización de Metadatos en DSpace 5.x

Tags: tomcat, xsl

Tengo una instalación limpia de DSpace 5.x en un Ubuntu 18.04. Uso el tema Mirage I que viene por defecto.

Necesito mostrar campos adicionales de Dublin Core dentro de la previsualización simple de mi Item.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He modicado el archivo que está dentro del directorio:
/dspace/webapps/xmlui/themes/Mirage/lib/aspect/artifactbrowser/item-view.xsl

Tal y como lo indica esta otra pregunta
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074688/how-to-show-custom-metadata-in-dspaces-summary-view

Sin embargo no logro hacer que aparescan los nuevos campos. Mi registro ya cuenta con los campos que deseo ver. Ya he parado y reiniciado el servicio de Tomcat y no logro hacer que aparescan. Hace falta hacer algo más? Estoy omitiendo algún otro paso para que se me refresque la vista?